# Django -- messing with the test server -- 304 errors and such

Tags: django, django-testing

While working on my webapp (which requires a login for the entire site) I noticed a funny "glitch" (if you can call it that). I was viewing my Django site, logged into the site (on the test server) in Chrome. I then logged out of my site and closed Chrome entirely.

I then opened Firefox and pasted in the URL to my Django site, expecting to be taken to the login page. However, I was not asked to log in, but rather was already logged in. So I proceeded to log out of the site and close Firefox.

I then re-opened Chrome to log in, only to find that there was no CSS styling. I logged in and the whole site had lost its CSS styling and the test server kept given the `304` errors for all CSS and IMG files.

I've figured out that the `304` error has something to do with time mis-matching (like Django thinking I was logged out, but in Firefox I was logged in -- so now it is confused).

I was just wondering if this is avoidable, or if it is a "feature" of the test server? Will this kind of thing happen in production mode too?

### EDIT for clarity of what I'm asking:

Will the loss of styling and images due to the 304 error that I am experiencing with the Django test server ***continue to occur*** when I launch the webapp with Apache?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've got questions about three things:

1. Why you were logged in in Firefox.
2. Why you lost your CSS styling in Chrome.
3. What all those 304 responses are.

Unfortunately there are quite a few possible explanations for the first two issues you're seeing. Most likely there's nothing too serious going wrong.

For the first two issues you could try reverting to a fresh state and then seeing if the problems still occur. e.g. Use a clean Django database (with no sessions) and try to clear all your cached browser information (cookies, auth, cached files). Admittedly this is quite a time consuming way to test for problems, but its the best general advice I can give without being able to examine your situation directly.

Luckily 304 responses aren't a problem at all. A 304 just means that the browser has the file in its cache. See [Conditional View Processing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/conditional-view-processing/):

> When the client next requests the same resource, it might send along a header such as If-modified-since, containing the date of the last modification time it was sent, or If-none-match, containing the ETag it was sent. If the current version of the page matches the ETag sent by the client, or if the resource has not been modified, a 304 status code can be sent back, instead of a full response, telling the client that nothing has changed.

Comment: Q1)I know that Firefox had saved my password - not what I'm asking. ---- Q2)Indeed, why does the 304 kill all the styling and images? ----Q3)I know that they have to do with timestamp mismatches - not what I'm asking. My question is whether this behaviour will also be present when I run the webapp with Apache. (I will edit the question for clarity).